# How do you change the category of an app in the Applications launcher?

Tags: applications, slingshot

In the Applications menu, I have some programs that are showing up under the "Other" category, that I'd like moved to other categories.

I tried dragging and dropping, and the only context menu action is *Add to Dock*. How do I change the category?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can acheive this by changing the content of the *.dektop file for the respective application.

You can usually find these here:

```
/usr/share/applications/
```

Just open the respective file and in the `[Desktop Entry]` section of the file for example add the the following in order put the entry in the "Office" section:

```
Categories=Office;
```

Use `Network` for the Internet section, etc. Just look at entries for apps in the respective sections in order to find out the correct string for the section you want.

You can also install alacarte, this offers you a gui enabling you to edit menu entries. This does not work 100% reliably on elementary in my experience, though. [Here](http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-edit-dash-application-results#install-alacarte) is a short explanation.

```
sudo apt-get install alacarte
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: It's fair to notice that this does work, but a lot of program's will override this change when they update. So if the program suddenly goes back to it's old category, its probably an update.

Comment: Great, thanks. For those also looking to change the category of Google Chrome Apps that are appearing, these .desktop entries can be modified under `~/.local/share/applications`.   

(Right-clicking on the Chrome Apps list and choosing "Create shortcuts" allows you to add additional apps to the Application Menu.)